# How can I make a flexbox constrain image height?

Tags: css, flexbox

CSS Flexbox newbie here.

I'm trying to achieve a layout with

- A fixed-height header
- A content area that takes up all available space, and displays an image.
- A fixed-height footer

[image]

I got this working with the following flexbox code:

```html
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <body style="height: 100%;">
  
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
            <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1)";>
                Header
            </div>
    
            <div style="flex: 1; background-color: gray;">        
                content
            </div>
    
            <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)">
                Footer
            </div>
        </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

This works great. Now I want to display an image inside of the content area. With small images, this works fine:

```
<!-- Inside the content div... -->
<img src="..." />
```

[image]

However, with large images, **the image overflows its container** :-(

[image]

(Notice how the pony is extending past the content area, overlapping the footer, and beyond.)

I've tried setting *max-height: 100%* on the img, but it still overflows the container. How can I fix this?

Comment: After posting this question, I realized I could make this work by getting rid of the <img> element and instead setting background-image on the content div, background-size: contain, background-repeat: no-repeat. Nonetheless, I'm curious how to contain an <img> inside of a flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Using the SVG images will not hamper the quality of the picture,
when you decrease or increase the size of the image, below code will
also works fine with the responsive layout.

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;">
  
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
            <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1)";>
                Header
            </div>
    
            <div style="flex: 1; background-color: gray;">        
                content
                <img src="dog.svg" id="imge" />
            </div>
    
            <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)">
                Footer
            </div>
        </div>  
  </body>
</html>

#imge{
      position:absolute;
      width: 99%;
      margin-left: -3%;
      height: 96%;
}
```

Comment: .jpg and .png images are not able to retain the quality of the images when it is stretched or shrink ,if you use the svg images , it will help you .

Comment: I don't want to stretch the image. I want to shrink the contain the image; that is, shrink it if necessary while preserving aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

I am a flexbox newbie also, so I don't know how / or if flexbox could achieve this.

But css background image can easily do this... 
(No IE >= 8 Support ) http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

I just added a div in the content area.
Set it to absolute position, top,right,bottom, and left to 0.
(And don't forget to set its parent to relative position.)

Then you set it to:

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
```

http://codepen.io/xenocide/pen/xGwaBm/

Comment: Yeah, if you look in the comments to the original question, I made the same discovery. However, I'd still like to know how to do this with an image element, rather than a CSS background image style.